# How to merge the content of two cell table in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a list of CellTables. How can I merge the row of both table and returned the result. 
For example

```
List<CellTable> cellTables = new ArrayList<CellTable>();
celltables.add(table1);
celltables.add(table2);
celltables.add(table3);
```

I am using following approach

```
private CellTable fetchAllCellTables() {
            CellTable table=new CellTable();
            for(CellTable tempTable:cellTables){
                    int numRows = tempTable.getRowCount();
                    table.setRowCount(numRows+1);
                    table.setRowData((List) tempTable.getLayoutData());
            }
            return table;

    }
```

but I am not able to see the total content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i think here would be best approach is using a `DataProvider` for each of the `CellTable`s as well as the final `CellTable`,

Sample Code :

```
// Create a CellList.
CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(new TextCell());

// Create a data provider.
MyDataProvider dataProvider = new MyDataProvider();

// Add the cellList to the dataProvider.
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellList);

// Get the underlying list from data dataProvider.
List<String> list = dataProvider.getList();

// Add the value to the list. The dataProvider will update the cellList.
list.add(newValue); // you can do this in a loop so that you merge all values
```

For your scenario as you are using a `List` of `CellTable`, you will have to likewise keep a `List` of respective `DataProvider`s

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to make one big table that displays the rows of your small tables:

```
table1                       table2
col1 | col2 | col3           col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
------------------           -------------------------
a    | b    | c              1    | 2    | 3    | 4

big table
col1 | col2 | col3 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
----------------------------------------------
a    | b    | c    | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4
```

with e.g.

```
CellTable<String[]> table1 = new CellTable<String[]>();
table1.addColumn( new Column<String[], String>(new TextCell()){

    public String getValue(String[] object){
        return object[0];
    }

}, "col1");
```

---

**This solution only works if you can edit the source code constructing the small tables!**

I would first define a row object class that contains the entire information of a single row in the big table, e.g.

```
public class RowObject{

    public String[] table1RowObject; // the class of the field should be the generic
                                     // type of the table1 CellTable

    public MyObject table2RowObject; // the class of the field should
                                     // be the generic type of table2

    // ... other tables

}
```

Now change the generic types of the small tables to `RowObject`:

```
CellTable<RowObject> table1 = new CellTable<RowObject>();
table1.addColumn ( new Column<RowObject, String>(new TextCell()){

    public String getValue(RowObject object){
        // The data of table1 has been moved into the table1RowObject
        // old: String[] object; return object[0];
        return object.table1RowObject[0];
    }

}, "col1" );
```

Then the big table can easily be constructed like this:

```
CellTable<RowObject> bigTable = new CellTable<RowObject>();
for (CellTable<RowObject> ct : tablesList){
    for (int i = 0; i < ct.getColumnCount(); i++)
        bigTable.addColumn( ct.getColumn(i) );
}
```

Load the data for all tables at the same time with the help of a data provider, e.g.

```
ListDataProvider<RowObject> dataSource = new ListDataProvider<RowObject>();
dataSource.addDataDisplay( table1 );
dataSource.addDataDisplay( table2 );
dataSource.addDataDisplay( bigTable );
```

and then as soon as you update the `dataSource` all small tables get updated at the same time as the big table.